# How to use a random number generator to determine path in "if" statement

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use a random number to determine if an event will happen using an `if` statement.

I keep getting the following error:

```
 lunarlander.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected '='
    if (numb % = 2)*
```

Here is the code:

```
def space_travel
    puts "\n"
    puts "You engage the main thrusters and you feel the ship jerk forward."
    numb = rand(10)
    if (numb % == 2)
        puts "Everything functions as expected. You settle in for the trip."
    else
        spacewalk()
    end
end
```

Comment: you got a syntax error on line 13.

Comment: In future, please consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. A quick selection may discourage other answers and may not be appreciated by those still working on their answers. Most members wait at least a couple of hours; some wait much longer, giving then-sleeping members around the world a chance to respond. The point is that there is no rush to make a selection.

Comment: To add to what @CarySwoveland said: Consider whether you want to immediately select the first answer that appears, and then later one that is much more elegant appears... do you switch selected answers... do you remove the initial code from your code? It takes 24 hours for the world to rotate, and many potential answerers won't respond until the weekend.

Comment: @Mike : What is the expected outcome if the minimum value occurs more than once? Would you like then to get the first key in the hash, or a random one of those which match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the second argument for modulo operator (`%`). Now you have

```
 numb % == 2
```

and you need to insert a number (or a numeric variable) between modulo and equals, e.g.

```
numb % 5 == 2
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP means to check if the number is even (`numb % 2 == 0`), better written `numb.even?`. I'd have upvoted your answer had you not asked for an upvote and acceptance from a newbie when the question was only eight minutes old.

Comment: See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)" and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, folks, it's very valuable!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I see your point with waiting to see other answers, as there can be multiple ways to write it. I changed it to use numb.even? as that does seem cleaner.